# Bootstrap 4 accordion card with flexbox table has white space

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a BS4 accordion with a flexbox table in the card body.  The body has a lot of white space under the table, but I'm not seeing where it's coming from.  I've tried replicating the issue in a normal container, but it doesn't happen. Flexbox'd tables don't seem to play well with accordion, because I can remove the flex classes and it works.

CodePen to what I'm seeing: https://codepen.io/shavertech/pen/QJjOwX

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="accordion" class="col">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <span class="float-left">
<h5>General <small><br>General conversation</small></h5>
</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="row card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr class="d-flex">
                  <th class="col-8">Forum</th>
                  <th class="col-1">Topics</th>
                  <th class="col-1">Posts</th>
                  <th class="col-2">Last Post</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="d-flex">
                  <td class="col-8">Support</td>
                  <td class="col-1">topic count</td>
                  <td class="col-1">post count</td>
                  <td class="col-2">Last Post Date</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="d-flex">
                  <td class="col-8">Support2</td>
                  <td class="col-1">topic count</td>
                  <td class="col-1">post count</td>
                  <td class="col-2">Last Post Date</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="accordion" class="col">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <span class="float-left">
<h5>support <small><br>All Support</small></h5>
</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="row card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="accordion" class="col">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <span class="float-left">
<h5>support2 <small><br></small></h5>
</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="row card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen to NON-Flexbox version:https://codepen.io/shavertech/pen/RqryJb

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="accordion" class="col">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <span class="float-left">
<h5>General <small><br>General conversation</small></h5>
</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="row card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                  <th>Forum</th>
                  <th>Topics</th>
                  <th>Posts</th>
                  <th>Last Post</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Support</td>
                  <td>topic count</td>
                  <td>post count</td>
                  <td>Last Post Date</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Support2</td>
                  <td>topic count</td>
                  <td>post count</td>
                  <td>Last Post Date</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="accordion" class="col">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <span class="float-left">
<h5>support <small><br>All Support</small></h5>
</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="row card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="accordion" class="col">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <span class="float-left">
<h5>support2 <small><br></small></h5>
</span>
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse3">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="row card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CodePen not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix that you should apply `flex-wrap: nowrap;` on `.card`.

```
.card {
   position: relative;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -ms-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column;
   min-width: 0;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-clip: border-box;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
   border-radius: .25rem;
   flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Key Line */
}
```